# Unquoting in Nested Macros in Racket

Tags: macros, racket

#### Context

The language is [`#lang web-server/insta`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/web-server/run.html#%28mod-path._web-server%2Finsta%29) and this code will be generated inside a quasiquoted argument passed to [`response/xexpr`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/web-server/http.html#%28def._%28%28lib._web-server%2Fhttp%2Fxexpr..rkt%29._response%2Fxexpr%29%29)

#### The Call

```
-> (define home 'home-page)
-> (make-navigation home "home-page")
```

#### Current Output

Note the ` backquote before `((href , (embed/url ...`

```
'(p ((id "home-page")) (a `((href ,(embed/url home-page))) "home-page"))
```

#### Desired Output

Note that the ` is gone.

```
'(p ((id "home-page")) (a ((href ,(embed/url home-page))) "home-page"))
```

#### Current Code

```
(define (make-navigation uri label)

  (define (make-id uri)
    `((id ,(symbol->string uri))))

  (define-syntax-rule (embed uri)
    ``((href ,(embed/url ,uri))))

  `(p ,(make-id uri)
      (a ,(embed uri)
     ,label)))
```

#### Problem Locus

The issue is probably with `embed`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#lang racket
(define (make-navigation uri label)

  (define (make-id uri)
    `((id ,(symbol->string uri))))

  (define-syntax-rule (embed uri)
    '((href ,(embed/url uri))))

  `(p ,(make-id uri)
      (a ,(embed uri)
     ,label)))

(define home 'home-page)
(make-navigation home "home-page")
```

Output:

```
'(p ((id "home-page")) (a ((href ,(embed/url uri))) "home-page"))
```

UPDATE

```
(define (make-navigation uri label)

  (define (make-id uri)
    `((id ,(symbol->string uri))))

  (define-syntax-rule (embed uri)
    `((href ,(list 'unquote (list 'embed/url uri)))))

  `(p ,(make-id uri)
      (a ,(embed uri)
     ,label)))

(define home 'home-page)
(make-navigation home "home-page")
```

Output:

```
'(p ((id "home-page")) (a ((href ,(embed/url home-page))) "home-page"))
```

Comment: Missed that. New attempt.

Comment: I've been struggling with controlling evaluation and non-evaluation and the `,(list 'unquote (list 'my-function my-args)` looks like a useful and illustrative pattern. Thanks.

Comment: It's not exactly pretty.

Comment: Working is sweet enough... *Syntactic sugar causes cancer of the semicolon. -- Alan J. Perlis*

Comment: Turning `define-syntax-rule` into `define` tidies it up a little.